# Algorithm for Approximate Social Security Number Match Search

Tags: algorithm, match, autohotkey

I wrote an application to link files according the client's social security numbers, but sometimes the client wrote 1 or 2 digits incorrectly. What are the algorithms I can deploy to return an approximate match?

Correctly I implemented a wild card function, allow me to search through the database if the hand writing is bad. But sometimes the hand writing is fine (they just wrote it incorrectly).

```
; Function to get the new SSN
; Keep in mind the searchCount is reset at the end of this function only.
; =============================================================================
GetSSN() {
    Global searchCount
    UserInput = Blank
    Length := StrLen(UserInput)

    while (Length < 9) 
    {
        InputBox, UserInput, Please Enter the SSN,,, 350, 100
        Length := StrLen(UserInput)
    }

    ; Use the SubStr method to extract the first character of the ssn
    firstCharacterOfInput := SubStr(UserInput, 1, 1)

    if (firstCharacterOfInput = 0) {
        StringTrimLeft, UserInput, UserInput, 1
    }

    ; Replace the wild card key "*" with the implementation required "."
    StringReplace, UserInput, UserInput, *,.

    ; Depend if the key contains a wild card, use normal / wild card search
    IfInString, UserInput, . 
    {
        ; MsgBox, WildCardSearch
        mFileName := WildCardSearch(UserInput)
    } else {
        ; MsgBox, NormalSearch
        mFileName := GetFileName(UserInput)
    }

    DrawFileName(mFileName)
    ; Reset searchCount for next time use
    searchCount = 0
}

; Function for wild card implementation
; Reference: http://www.adarshr.com/papers/wildcard
; The implementation used the RegEXMatch Expression
; =============================================================================
WildCardSearch(key) {
    Global dataCount, searchCount, DataBaseArray

    Loop, %dataCount% {
        currentLine := DataBaseArray%searchCount%_1
        FoundPos := RegExMatch(currentLine, key)

        if (FoundPos != 0) {
            result := DataBaseArray%searchCount%_2
            return result
        }
        searchCount += 1
    }

    notFoundMapName = Unable to find the member %A_Now%.jpg
    return notFoundMapName
}
```

Comment: What programming language and for which country ?

Comment: @PaulR: The language is the Autohotkey scripting language, and as the poster referred to SSN, I'd suspect it's the US.

Comment: @PaulR: The SSN is from United States. The format is ###-##-####. For example: 123-45-6789. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to build an approximate match out of exact lookup. Divide the SSN up into three fields. If there are only two errors, at least one of those fields must be free of errors. So build three tables, each of them allowing you to retrieve all of the SSNs that match exactly on one of the fields.

Given an approximate SSN, retrieve all of the exact matches from each of the three tables, indexed by the three fields you have broken it into, and check the SSNs retrieved to see if any of them has no more than two characters wrong.

Comment: Building on this, you could create a table for each of the 9*8=72 ways of selecting 7 characters from the total of 9.  Every SSN with at most 2 errors must have 7 characters that exactly match some SSN in the DB, so just loop through the 72 subsets, looking up the corresponding subset of characters from the given SSN in each table: if a lookup finds *any* results, they are automatically (<=2)-error candidates.  There can be at most 10*10 results per lookup, for a total of at most 7200 records examined -- by comparison, 3-way splitting could need up to 3,000,000 row checks.

Comment: Whoops, too late to edit my comment, but there are in fact only 9*8/2=36 ways of selecting 7 characters from 9 without regard to order, so my idea is even better than I thought :-P

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to check if two strings are nearly the same is to use levenshtein distance. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance This returns a number and the higher the number the more different the two are.

The only problem with this is that levenshtein requires both inputs to calculate a distance so you cannot compute against all entries in a database rapidly.  The algorithm is expensive when performed in bulk.

Of course you can combine this with Mcdowellas idea, then you have reduced the volume to at least 1/1000th.

Comment: True, it's not the fastest, but it is still worth the mention.